# user's text input - mobile prefix should limit the amount of digits being entered.

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: img]
I have an input for mobile prefix and number:

```
  <div class="two columns">
    <input class="sgprefix" id="mobileprefix" name="mobileprefix" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="nine columns">
     <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" class="input numeric-only">
    </div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that - if the user entered the value 65 in mobile prefix it will limit the mobile number to 8 digits.

I don't want to use maxlength as that will limit it to 8 forever

Comment: And it is an absolute given that a mobile number can not start with 65 _after_ the prefix?

Comment: I'm not I follow your question -  
I only want to check if user entered the value 65 then it limits the mobile number digit to 8 digits,

Comment: I am asking, what if the user’s mobile number starts with 65 _after_ the prefix - i.e., their number would be 6565… – would it even make sense to limit the number of digits to 8 in that situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
$('#mobile').keyup(function(){    
var count=$('#mobileprefix').val();
        if(count=="65"){
           $(this).attr('maxlength','8');
        }
    else{
      $(this).attr('maxlength','10');    }
});
```

If you want to remove the `maxlength` attribute use this code :

```
$(this).removeAttr('maxlength');
```

EDIT: check below code , it will change accordingly if you change the value of `#mobileprefix`.

```
(function(){

    $('#mobile').keyup(function(){    
var count=$('#mobileprefix').val();
        if(count=="65"){
           $(this).attr('maxlength','8');

        }
    else{
      $(this).removeAttr('maxlength');   }
});

$('#mobileprefix').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="65"){
        $('#mobile').val($('#mobile').val().substring(0,8));
        }
    }); 
    }());
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/NIHAR_SARKAR/489s4Ls1/)

Answer (score 1):

You may use following code snippet to serve your purpose. When value of `.sgprefix` changes, check whether it is `65` if so, set `maxlength` attribute for number field, otherwise remove `maxlength` attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sgprefix').change( function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 65) {
      $('#mobile').attr('maxlength', 8);
    } else {
      $('#mobile').removeAttr('maxlength');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="two columns">
  <input class="sgprefix" id="mobileprefix" name="mobileprefix" type="text">
</div>
<div class="nine columns">
  <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" class="input numeric-only">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achive that with javascript. You can register a keyup event on your mobileprefix. When keyup action is performed, you check for the length of the value and if it is 2 you set the maxLength to 6, otherwise you set it 8. Probably you want to add some action if the user only adds 1 digit or to checkup if there are really digits added.

```js
document.getElementById("mobileprefix").onkeyup = function() {
  if (document.getElementById("mobileprefix").value == '65') {
    document.getElementById("mobile").setAttribute("maxLength", 8);
  } 
  else {
    document.getElementById("mobile").removeAttribute("maxLength");
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="two columns">
  <input class="sgprefix" id="mobileprefix" name="mobileprefix" type="text">
</div>
<div class="nine columns">
  <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" class="input numeric-only">
</div>
```

Comment: I only want to check if user entered the value 65 then it limits the mobile number digit to 8 digits, I also prefer to use the class sgprefix so I can apply it to a different prefix fields